# Fix localhost cant provide a secure connection

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I accidently configured  a web-app to force a secure connection i.e. https, and although I have turned this off, I cannot get chrome to forget this error, so whenever I ask for the url of my local development server;

```
 http://localhost:3000/
```

Chrome instead returns

```
https://localhost:3000/
```

and gives the error

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
```

I have tried `Chrome/Clear Browsing data` and this does not help.  The app uses ruby on rails and the secure connection was done by setting   [config.force_ssl = true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476254/1299362).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the same thing happen when using a different browser (e.g. Firefox, Safari)? I'm asking to see if it's an issue with Chrome or perhaps http/https redirection on the app

Comment: Exactly how did you configure your app to force a secure connection? Did you use a HTTP redirect? - If so, was it 301, 307, or?  - Or did you use HSTS to force a secure connection? If so, with which parameters? - The answers to these questions are necessary in order to determine what you need to do to solve your problem.

Comment: It is a ruby on rails app, and I put in the configuration file ``` config.force_ssl = true```. if you look here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476254/1299362, you can see that it does quite a lot.  I can see why jsoegaard asked how it was configured, quite a lot happens. I will edit the question to include this information.

Comment: Dials Mavis, it affects Firefox and Safari, but just resetting the cache fixes it for those browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going for the nuclear option, uninstalling chrome and using [this post](http://crunchify.com/how-to-purge-all-your-google-chrome-user-data-on-mac-os-x/) to delete all my google-chrome data. It worked. Note that just uninstalling chrome did not work.

Answer (score 22):

As this is only your development site on localhost, and not a real domain name, you can solve the problem in Chrome by opening the following URL:

```
chrome://net-internals/#hsts
```

You must open this URL in Chrome.

From there you get the settings for HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security). Then under "Delete domain" put in localhost and delete it from the list.

If you have used other local names than localhost to refer to your development setup, delete those as well.

Comment: Tried deleting localhost, localhost:3000, 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0:3000, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:3000, all to no avail.

Comment: deleting `localhost` and also clearing `chrome://history/` did it for me

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 10):

I always find adding a fake query string after the URL refreshes the cache for me.

e.g. http://localhost:3000/?fake=true

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to use http rather than https